# Grep-ing from multiple files

Tags: grep, gzip

I have a lot of log files with format `foo.log.[1-100].gz`, and another one `detail-20161205-[00-23]`. Need to find some string from multiple files.

I'm trying to do the following:

`zfgrep String foo.log.[45-64].gz`,

but I'm always getting wrong output, not from mentioned files.
Thus, I want to understand how to `grep` from .gz files and from not .gz (from the second format). Can I use commands other than `grep` as well?

Comment: (Also if that doesn't work, what shell are you using exactly?)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to do something like `grep String foo.log.{1..100}.gz` and `grep String detail-20161205-{00..23}`. If not all the files exist in that range, you can add the `-s` option so you don't see all the errors.

```
grep -s String foo.log.{1..100}.gz
```

What `detail-20161205-[00-23]` does for example is expand to `0`, `0-2`, `3`, leading to the wrong files being searched.

Comment: With {} output is: _No such file or directory_

Comment: What's the output of `echo {01..10}` for you?

Comment: _01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10_

Comment: If not all the files exist, it will throw some errors, but should still work normally. You can pass `-s` (see answer) to prevent that. Did it at least output what you expected in addition to the errors?

Comment: I'm trying to grep example from [64-89].gz, but there is an output from [8-9], and without any errors.

Comment: In the case of just in the range 64 to 89, then use {64..89}.

Comment: {64..89} - this helped. Thank you.